# What is wrong with the following inheritance/mix in in Scala?

Tags: scala

Basically I want to be able to mix in live or historical processing into my algorithm.  The following does not compile.

```
// Event driven processing
class Event {

}

// Live events (as opposed to historical)
trait Live extends Event {

}

class Algorithm {

}

new Algorithm with Live
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By declaring `trait Live extends Event`, you specify that `Live` can only be applied to subclasses of `Event`. Later, you're trying to apply it to `Algorithm`, which is not a subclass of `Event`, hence the compiler complains.

Depending on your original intent (not clear from that snippet), you may want to either:

- Declare `Event` as a trait itself;
- Have `Algorithm` extend `Event`.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing multiple classes inheritance there. if trait `Live` extends `Event`, your type `Algorithm with Live` has two class ancestors, `Event` and `Algorithm`. This is forbidden. what you want to do is not clear, but if it is possible to make `Event` a trait rather than a class, it should work. `trait Live extends Event` imply that  `Live` has to be mixed with `Event` or a subclass. So if `Algorithm` can extend `Event` (doesn't sound likely), that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

The complete example would be:

```
// Event driven processing. Must be a trait due to didierd's comment
// and Jean-Philippe's comment
trait Event

// Live events (as opposed to historical)
trait Live extends Event

// Self typing isn't strictly needed but generally it's not much use without it
// as I assume you're going to want to use methods of the Event within your
// Algorithm
class Algorithm { self: Event =>
}

val t = new Algorithm with Live
```